# How do i do an ESP32 HTTPupdate from private GitHub repository

Tags: http, github, https, esp32, arduino-ide

The previous Question on this forum got me close do updating an esp32 from a private GitHub repository .bin via the HTTPUpdate method. I got success with a public repo, but am now struggling with editing the httpupdate.cpp to correctly authenticate with git. I have done all that is stated in this original post. For the sake of brevity only repo URLs were changed to my specific needs.

[Initial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62333061/how-i-do-an-esp8266-httpupdate-via-private-github-repository/62437312#62437312)

Comment: Are you asking for help editing httpupdate.cpp or have you made a change and it's not working? If it's not working, how is it failing? Is it not compiling, is the ESP32 crashing, are you getting HTTP errors, or something else?

Comment: I have changed the httpupdate.cpp, successfully compiled and uploaded. Instead of the usual 404 response i now get 403 which as far as I know is the server understanding the request yet not allowing me access. Some posts mentioned that User-Agent must be set and I checked, httpupdate.cpp already does that by default. I would like to see the request that my ESP is making to the server, perhaps I can gleam more info from that, but not too sure how to go about this.